# JavaScript как отсортировать массив с объектами

Tags: javascript

есть примерно такой массив с объектами

```
let array = [{id:"",count:12},{id:"",count:14},{id:"",count:2},{id:"",count:1}]
```

Нужно сделать так чтоб этот массив был отсортирован от большего к меньчшему count, тоесть в итоге должно быть это:

```
let array = [{id:"",count:14},{id:"",count:12},{id:"",count:2},{id:"",count:1}]
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно сделать.

```js
let array = [{id:"",count:12},{id:"",count:14},{id:"",count:2},{id:"",count:1}]

array.sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count);

console.log(array)
```